# <a> tag with text overlay on image, hover effect cancelling image opacity when text is hovered

Tags: html, css

(hard to word this issue in the title)

I have links that are images with absolute header overlays. I want the opacity of the image to change when any part of the link is hovered. My problem is that when I hover over the text that is overlayed, it omits the :hover state applied to the image.

```css
.galleryItem img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: opacity(.7);
  transition: .3s;
}

.galleryItem a,
h4 {
  color: #f5f9e9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.galleryItem img:hover {
  filter: opacity(1);
}

.galleryItem h4 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="galleryItem">
  <a href="#">
    <h4>The Combinator</h4>
    <img src="img/fwaz.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

*I DO NOT want the opacity of the h4 tag to change at all. But again, I do need hovering the h3 to maintain the same changes I've applied to hovering the img.

I'm not sure how to remedy this problem at all.

Comment: "when I hover over the text that is overlayed, it omits the :hover state applied to the image." — without a working example it's hard for me to say, but with `z-index:10` on the h4 and that h4 block sitting "on top" of the image (in the z dimension) I would first guess that the img is not "seeing" the hover because it's on the h4. Hover propagates up the DOM tree, but not the z order. It might work if the img was enclosed in the h4 `<h4>text<img...></h4>` but then z-index would get in the way again. Why not set the img as a background-image of the h4?

Comment: ", I do need hovering the h3 to maintain the same change" I see no `<h3>` in your code

Comment: @dickySOL Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pointer-events: none;` on the h4.

```css
.galleryItem {
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.galleryItem img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  filter: opacity(.7);
  transition: .3s;
}

.galleryItem a, h4 {
  color: #f5f9e9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.galleryItem img:hover {
  filter: opacity(1);
} 

.galleryItem h4 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="galleryItem">
  <a href="#">
    <h4>The Combinator</h4>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/360">                     
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: IF this is NOT it then the OP probably needs to update the clarity of the question. Looks good to me given the limited info.  I always forget about these pointer events for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Use hover on the parent**

The hover rule should be on a parent which wraps everything.
When parent is hovered, a child element gets styled, in this case an `<img>`. Parent could be `galleryItem` or `a`, whichever works better.

```
.galleryItem:hover img {
    filter: opacity(1);
}
```